# What is the maximum number of fields that can be indexed in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index, which has many hierarchal attributes. I am dynamically indexing all these attributes.

I want to know what is the maximum number of fields that can be stored in an index ?

Answer (score 6):

By default, the maximum number of fields is 1000, but this [can be changed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/mapping.html#mapping-limit-settings). You can increase that by changing the `index.mapping.total_fields.limit` index setting.

Also you can have at most 20 nesting levels for normal object fields (changeable with the `index.mapping.depth.limit` index setting) and 100 nested fields (changeable with the `index.mapping.nested_fields.limit` index setting).

Comment: I know I can increase it , but what is the maximum it can hold. Is it unlimited ?

Comment: That setting is a Java long internally, so in theory you could have `Long.MAX_VALUE` (= `2^63-1`) fields, but your index will probably break before that for other reasons :-)

Comment: @Val can you explain the reason in detail that why elasticsearch have put this limit of 1000.
And also is it ok if i have 2000 fields in my index?

Comment: @gaurav9620 they introduced that limit in order to prevent mapping explosion, but you can feel free to augment the limit if needed. For instance, all the index templates for Beats set that limit to 10000

Comment: @Val - Thanks a lot for the this. Also can you please explain this answer as according to this fields above 1000 can be harmful?
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/maximum-number-of-fields-in-an-index-mapping/90150/2

Comment: I have 100000 for my current setup, is that okay or it can do some problem later?

Comment: @GauravTewari There's a reason why it's set to 10000 by default. But if 100K works for you, then you might as well go with it. There's no right or wrong, it always depends on the specifics of your use case, data, etc